# How to perform async database queries inside the for_each closure of a channel receiver

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a `futures mpsc` that receives structs at random time intervals representing trading data which I process and then insert into a database
struct Trade_data {
id: i64,
data: Vec,
}

```
 async fn my_task(rx: mpsc::Receiver<Trade_data>) -> impl Future<Item = ()> {
    rx.for_each(move |trades| {

          async {
                let pool = pg_connection.connection_pool.unwrap().clone();
                let client = pool.get().await.unwrap();
                let statement = client.prepare("my query statement").await.unwrap();
                for trade_data in trades.data.iter() {
                     // construct query object from trade_data
                    let query = client.execute(&statement, &query_object);
                    query_futures.push(query);
                }
                let query_result = futures::future::join_all(query_futures).await;
                Ok(query_result)
           }
    })

}
```

I am using tokio-postgres, tokio and the bb8 connection pooling library.

You can see what I am doing is creating a combined join on all the queries, so the postgres client can pipeline them.

I do not understand the errors:

It says for impl Future<Item=()> `expected enum std::result::Result, found ()` and also `associated type Item not found`

And for the for_each it says the  `expected enum std::result::Result, found ()`

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: To start you off, the `Future` trait has an associated type called `Output` not `Item`. I'd start by changing that and update your answer with the new errors. See: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/future/trait.Future.html